# How to properly access an array's elements within a for loop?

Tags: javascript, html

I am currently trying to take an ArrayList that I recieved as a response from a servlet, and print it as a table. The array currently has 2 objects within it. Calling on those objects and their elements works just fine, ie.

theArray[1].amount

works just fine, returning the "amount" value within the first object in the array.

But when I try to use theArray[i].amount in a for loop, I'm being told "theArray[i] is undefined"?

Help please!

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Employee Reimbursements</title>
</head>
<body>

    
    <table id="myTable" style="border: solid 1px black; background-color: bisque;">


        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th width="100">Reimbursement ID</th>
                <th width="100">Amount in $</th>
                <th width="100">Time Submitted</th>
                <th width="100">Time Resolved</th>
                <th width="100">Description</th>
                <th width="100">Reimbursement Author</th>
                <th width="100">Reimbursement Resolver</th>
                <th width="100">Status ID</th>
                <th width="100">Type ID</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
           
        </tbody>
    </table>
   
 <script>
     var table = document.getElementById('myTable');

     var theArray = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('reimbArray'));

     var length = theArray.length;
     var i=1;

     console.log(theArray[1].amount);

    for(i=1; i <= length; i++) {
        var row = table.insertRow(i);
            
        var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
        cell1.innerHTML = theArray[i].reimbId;
        var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
        cell2.innerHTML = theArray[i].amount;
        }

 </script>

<script src="scripts/index.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I think you want to initialize `i=0` in your `for` loop and change the condition to `i < length`.  Javascript arrays are zero-based.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In code we start counting from `0`, so your loop needs some adjustments. You are doing:

`for(i=1; i <= length; i++)`

so the index will go `1`, `2` for an array of length 2. But you want to go `0`, `1`.

So either start from 0 with `for(i=0; i < length; i++)`, or substract the offset in your array access: `theArray[i - 1].amount;`

Comment: That was exactly the problem, thank you so much! I'm very new to coding, so little mistakes like this are always popping up.

Comment: Glad it helped. When you're satisfied make sure to mark the answer as correct so its visible to everyone that this question is solved already.

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried to use the [`forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) function for `Javascript`?

It may help you.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.